# How to connect phantom wallet by Solana Pay using Web3.js?

Tags: javascript, solana-web3js

I am trying connect Phantom wallet from Solana Pay using Web3.js However I am constantly getting the error "Buffer is not defined". How to resolve this?

Note: I am not using Nodejs. I am trying to create the integration with the Web3.js library.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
// The below is the code where I am getting the error



                    var transaction= new solanaWeb3.Transaction().add(
                        
                    );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `solana/web3.js v1.30.2`

Or install some extra dependencies for the latest version

I'm sharing a blog. It's based on ReactJS but hope you can understand.
And no issue, change your version to 1.30.2, and it will work fine.

[Blog_for_extra_dependencies](https://alchemy.com/blog/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5)

You can refer to this code also.
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/solana-transaction-code-1nu2wn)